# Does any information exist when Illegal access will be prohibited in Java, or in which version?

Tags: java, java-11, illegalaccessexception

I need to document some stuff for my Project.

We currently use "DocXStamper" to fill Word Documents with Java. But we are not allowed to migrate to a "safer" version (like apache POI) right now, and there are no Plans to migrate to a higher Java Version than 11 (for now).

But just in case I want to document it. Since DocXStamper relies on the "org.javassist" Dependency, which is not maintained since 2010.

Right now there are just Warnings like:

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions (file:path-to/org.javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/598244f595db5c5fb713731eddbb1c91a58d959b/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

But to minimize and acknowledge possible technical dept and risk, I want to document the legacy code with the "proper information".

I can not find any information to that topic, other than "just get rid of the dependency", which I am currently not allowed to do.

If you have and could give me further insight on that topic I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Looking at this library it has had it's latest update 12 days ago https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist but since it's entire purpose seems to revolve around reflection and bytecode manipulation it may be that when reflection bites the dust it's functionality is toast without loading up an external library to enable reflection again.

Comment: Question from the title was answered at a recent panel: https://youtu.be/rkZoHmZ2wlU?t=2662

Comment: The video says java 16 deny will be the default, but you can still enable it via command line flag it seems

Comment: Javassist is not problematic in general. The issue here is adding classes to the environment by invoking `defineClass` with access override on an existing class loader. There are legal alternatives, which will persist, like create a new class loader. Java 9 even added the special feature of adding dynamically created classes to your own package via `MethodHandles.lookup().defineClass(…)`. I’d say, it’s not Javassist but DocXStamper which needs maintenance.

Comment: Javaassist was updated to make use of Lookup.defineClass some time ago so this may be a case that the OP just needs to upgrade to a new version.

Comment: Note that even the latest Javassist will still fall back to `ClassLoader.defineClass()` in some cases: https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/blob/rel_3_27_0_ga/src/main/javassist/util/proxy/DefineClassHelper.java#L159